# converting 3D array into multiple csv files in python

Tags: python-3.x

I have an nparray named "x_unreal" with dimension (53, 30000,12).  I want to save the array as 53 multiple csv files with each file consisiting of 30000 rows and 12 columns.  How can i execute the same in python

My following attempts gave me error messages

Attempt 1

```
df_synthetic_wf = pd.DataFrame(x_unreal)
df_synthetic_wf.to_csv('df_synthetic_wfg.csv',index=False)
```

Error Message
ValueError: Must pass 2-d input. shape=(53, 30000, 12)

Attempt 2

```
savetxt('xunreal.csv', x_unreal, delimiter=',')
```

ValueError: Expected 1D or 2D array, got 3D array instead

Comment: You forgot to post your attempt at solving this problem.

Comment: Thanks, have shown my attempts.  What am I doing wrong

Comment: You want to write `arr[i, :, :]` for `i` going from `0` to `52`.

Comment: yes, precisely that is the need

Comment: Well, then do it! Do you know how you can loop over a range of integers?

Answer (score 1):

I implemented following code to get to the desired solution

```
for i in range(0,len(x_unreal)-1):
    recordname=str(i)
    record = x_unreal # returns numpy array record  
    record=np.asarray(record[0])
    path=recordname+".csv"
    np.savetxt(path,record,delimiter=",") #Writing the CSV for each record
    print("Files done: %s/%s"% (i,len(x_unreal)))
 
print("\nAll files done!")
```

All 53 files saved in directory as csv files